# Why can't I use an or statement in the filter function in elixir?

Tags: elixir

In elixir, if I operate on a list, getting multiples of 3:

```
1..10 |> Enum.filter(fn(x) -> (rem(x,3) == 0) end)
```

Outputs: `[3, 6, 9]`

---

Where as if I add an or statement:

```
1..10 |> Enum.filter(fn(x) -> (rem(x,3) == 0 || rem(x,5)) end)
```

Outputs: `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]`

---

Why does the or statement (which has been bracketed) give an unintended output?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`rem/2` will return an integer as its result - all integers are truthy in Elixir including `0`. This means `rem(x, 5)` is always truthy and the filter function will always yield true and keep all items. You probably intended to use:

```
iex(1)> 1..10 |> Enum.filter(fn(x) -> rem(x,3) == 0 || rem(x,5) == 0 end)
[3, 5, 6, 9, 10]
```